# Why are bounties one hour too long?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounty

I started a bounty seven days ago at 13:24.

[image]

At the moment, it is 13:31 (seven days later). At the moment, the bounty is still not over:

[image]

I guess this is a small bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The times are in UTC, not your local time (which I guess is CET, Central European Time).

It is currently 12:36 UTC, it won't be 13:24 UTC for another 50 or so minutes. The bounty ends exactly 7 days after it started.

There is a tooltip on the remaining duration that also shows the times (both in UTC):

[image: tooltip on the bounty time remaining area]